# How can I show Google Maps into a WebView?

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

When I click the button my app shows a map: it opens the google map perfectly in the browser safari.

Now I just want to show the map into a `UIWebView`.

Here is the code I use to show the map:

```
@IBAction func newAction(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    if (UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(NSURL(string:"comgooglemaps://")!)) {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string:
            "http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=" + self.longitud + "," + self.latitud + "&saddr=" + self.lat1 + "," + self.long1 + "&views=traffic")!)
    } else {
        mostrarAlerta("Por favor descarga e instala google map desde el AppleStore")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just display UIWebView on the IBAction?  You're going to want something like this:

```
@IBAction func newAction(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

    // set up webview
    let webView = UIWebView(frame: self.view.frame) // or pass in a CGRect frame of your choice

    // add webView to current view
    self.view.addSubview(webView)
    self.view.bringSubviewToFront(webView)

    // load the Google Maps URL
    webView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=" + self.longitud + "," + self.latitud + "&saddr=" + self.lat1 + "," + self.long1 + "&views=traffic")!))
}
```

Comment: It's working for me, are you sure you're implementing my answer properly?  http://i.stack.imgur.com/12VIc.png

Comment: how to show a go back to app button at top? simillar when you open google maps

Comment: @Engineeroholic that button in that status bar appears when you leave your app to navigate to a different app.

Comment: so the only solution is to make the webview under app navigation bar? but how to do it? :)

Comment: @Engineeroholic you should ask a new question.

Comment: nah I will just research it, btw the link at top did not work with me, however this worked ""https://maps.google.com?saddr&daddr=\(coordinates-here)"